# How do I remove JSON objects that are undefined

Tags: reactjs, mapping

I have Json array loaded in API

I called them using

```
categories.map((i,j) =>{
  return (<Tab label={'' + i.Name} key={j}/> );
})
```

**It displays as Fashion , Health , undefined , undefined , undefined**, since the numbers from 141 to 321 are undefined.

How do I prevent `undefined` from printing in the answer? Thank you.

Comment: What do you want to print instead? Empty string for the name or no Tab at all?

Comment: No tab at all. Just Fashion Health.

Comment: Someone's downvoted every answer without adding any explanation whatsoever... nice.

Comment: Yes Chris, Thank you so much for your answer and i'm unable to upvote since i don't have reputation.

Comment: @PremKumar i've updated my answer with a react example as well.

Comment: @Chris indeed. you got my vote as it's contributing to others like you mentioned.

Comment: Thank you so much @Sag1v :) Very much appreciated for your efforts

Comment: @Chirs You got my vote also, now I'm able to vote :-)

Comment: I'm just curious, why is your API returning `undefined`?

Comment: @MarkRabey The undefined values in API will be defined later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can conditionally return it:

```
categories.map((i,j) =>{
  return (i.svcName && <Tab label={'' + i.svcName} key={j}/> );
})
```

**UPDATE**
React example:

```js
const arr = [{
    val: 1
  },
  {
    val: 2
  },
  {
    val: false
  },
  {
    val: ''
  },
  {
    noval: 'blahh'
  },
  {
    val: 3
  },
  {
    val: undefined
  },
  {
    val: 4
  },
]

const Tab = ({ value }) => <div className="tab">{value}</div>;

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
      {
        arr.map((obj, i) => obj.val && <Tab value={obj.val} key={i} />)
      }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.tab{
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  display:inline-block;
  background-color: #333;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

**EDIT**
As @Chris mentioned in his answer, my approach will exclude [falsy values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) such as `null`,  `undefined`, `""`, `0`, `NaN` etc.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to first check if the value is not undefined for each item in the array:

```
categories.map((i,j) =>{
  return (i.svcName !== undefined && <Tab label={'' + i.svcName} key={j}/> );
});
```

This explicitly checks that `svcName` is not `undefined`, however `null`, empty string or any other falsy value would pass the evaluation.

If you want to check against falsy values, go for @Sag1v's suggestion.

Comment: yeah, i made it check for falsy as this property name `svcName` implies it should hold a string (not empty) and by the OP's example i guess he wants to render a tab with a title on it. so no point on rendering falsy values. but you wrote an important explanation about it. i think i should add it on my answer as well

Comment: Yes, it says. TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of null

Comment: @Sag1v, correct. But given OPs question I thought I'd add an answer that checks explicitly for `undefined` since you had already covered falsy values. Possible future readers might be looking for undefined and not falsy, hence why I posted this.

Comment: I don't think this answer should be downvoted, until someone explains why i upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a result of map function like `[el, el, el, false, el, el]` you should use filter before:

```
categories.filter(el => el.svcName !== undefined).map((i,j) =>{
  return (<Tab label={'' + i.svcName} key={j}/> );
})
```

Comment: While this will yield the desired output, you are effectively looping the array twice, which is probably not desirable.

Comment: But you will not have a result of map like `[el, el, el, false, el, el]`

Comment: You will return falsy values like `false` and empty strings etc + you are making a double iteration

Comment: @Sag1v, 'falsy values' could you explain little more, please?

Comment: @Andrew read my answer and see the example + there is a link to the DOCS  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy

Comment: `let newArr = arr.map(i => i.val && console.log("this is " + i.val));
console.log(newArr)` try to run this and check log of `newArr`.

Comment: but it wont render it. react wont render falsy values (`null` for example) and i believe this is the OP's target, to not render `Tabs` when it's undefined value

Answer (score 0):

With `Array#Filter` & `Array#Map`

```
categories.filter(i => i.svcName !== undefined).map((x,i) => <Tab label={'' + x.svcName} key={i}/>);
```

Comment: You will return falsy values like empty strings etc + you are making a double iteration

Comment: @Sag1v. Ok thanks. You are right. But still can't understand why my answer is dvoted?

Comment: i don't know, wasn't me anyway.